# angular: uib-datepicker locale is not set dynamically

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-translate

Consider the following setup: I have a form with a angular-bootstrap datepicker (uib-datepicker-directive), which I want to serve with different languages, such that dates are shown in different formats.

I am changing the locale dynamically with the angular-dynamic-locale-module, by using information from the state parameters.

A date object is printed with correct language-specific format using the angular date filter: `{{vm.date | date:'fullDate'}}`

Unfortunately the formatting for the datepicker is not working immediately. When loading the page and call a set-locale function it needs a click into the datepicker to adjust the format of the month and click to the month and back to additionally adjust the translations for the weekdays.

I have created a plunkr to demonstrate the behaviour.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2HA8LI5SzUqx2jSmUdjn?p=preview

Does anyone know this behaviour? And if so, is there a way to fix this, preferably without messing up the datepicker directive?

Thanx in advance, micoud

Comment: Try applying `$Scope.$Apply` when changing locale

Comment: I am afraid, that is not working as well, I have considered this before (which I did not write earlier - sorry for that). There is already an apply in progress. Even a safe apply function s.a.: `function safeApply($scope, fn) {
                ($scope.$$phase || $rootScope.$$phase) ? fn : $scope.$apply(fn);
            }` does not work.

Comment: $scope.$on('$localeChangeSuccess', function() {  
        console.log('$localeChangeSuccess');

        var bak = new Date (vm.date); 
        vm.date = bak;
    });

Comment: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/749               Also excerpts from angular-dynamic-locale "After the locale is changed, the event '$localeChangeSuccess' will be triggered."

Comment: Added plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/LT8NZO1ZJ3DU87wKq2jV?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, Anirudh, this helps partly, as the month-field in the datepicker is translated accordingly. But the weekdays are still not translated. I think about implementing a wrapper-directive that recompiles upon $localeChangeSuccess. I cannot look into that right now, but will try this out and give feedback about this, soon.